# How to I redirect an old hash link to a new link using React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an old link like:

`/#!/login`

and I want to redirect it to:

`/login`

How can I do that redirect using react router?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you redirect a hash link using react router:

`<Redirect from="/#!/login" to="/login" />`

You can add it under `<Router \>`

```
export const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Redirect to="/home" from="/#!/home" />
        </div>
    </Router>
);
```

Comment: Why not simply use `<BrowserRouter>` instead of `<HashRouter>` in the first place?